# How to get random posts with specific IDs in SQL?

Tags: sql, random, posts

I need to fetch random posts which will be published in the index. I use this SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM mt_item WHERE item_id= 1,2,3,4 ORDER by rand() LIMIT 4
```

Cannot we use "rand()" with specific IDs? What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve this? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want `in` . . .

```
SELECT *
FROM mt_item 
WHERE item_id IN ( 1,2,3,4 )
ORDER by rand() LIMIT 4
```